# How to convert a string to variable through a loop and save it in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem. This is my PHP code to take one MySQL table and Insert the data into another MySQL table:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysql_connect("host","user","password"); 
    if (!$connect){ 
        die("Failed to connect to the database: ".mysql_error()); 
    } 
$kies_bd = mysql_select_db("eraenz_db1",$connect); 
    if (!$kies_bd){ 
        die("failed to choose from BD: ".mysql_error()); 
    } 
$query = "SELECT ListNumber FROM residential"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >10){ 
        $difference = mysql_num_rows($result1) - 10; 
        $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM residential ORDER BY id LIMIT 10, $difference"; 
        $result2 = mysql_query($myQuery); 

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO lisitngs
        (listnumber, mandatetype, listdate,expirydate, updatedate,virtualtoururl,status,propertyright,agnt_id, erfsize,erf_no, housesize,outbuildingsize,    bathroomoptions,closedusergroup,facingoptions,features,kitchenoptions,flatlet,parking,carport,price,numofbath,numofbed, numofgarages, numofkitchens, numofreception,numofstudies,numofdomesticbath,numofdomesticbed,numofoutsidetoil,off_id,ownershiptype, parkingdesc, pooloptions,pool,sellingreason,sfeatureoptions,roofoptions,roomoptions,walloptions,windowoptions, styleoptions,securityoptions,tempcontrol,streetname,streetnumber, suburb, propertycategory,propertytype,ss_name,agentcontactname,province,city, postalcode,email,listingstatus,feedtype, rates, levies)
        values ({$line['ListNumber']}','{$line['MandateType']}','{$line['ListDate']}','{$line['ExpiryDate']}','{$line['UpdateDate']}','{$line['VisualTourURL']}','{$line['Status']}','{$line['PropertyCategory']}','{$line['AgentI']}','{$line['SizeOfErf']}','{$line['StandNumber']}','{$line['SizeOfHouse']}','{$line['SizeOfOutBuildings']}','{$line['BathroomOptions']}','{$line['ClosedUserGroup']}','{$line['FacingDescrip']}','{$line['Features']}','{$line['KitchenOptions']}','{$line['Flatlet']}','{$line['Parking']}','{$line['NumOfCarports']}','{$line['ListPrice']}','{$line['NumOfBathrooms']}','{$line['NumOfBedrooms']}','{$line['NumOfGarages']}','{$line['NumOfKitchens']}','{$line['NumReceptionRooms']}','{$line['NumStudies']}','{$line['NumOfDomBathrooms']}','{$line['NumOfDomBedrooms']}','{$line['NumOfOutSideToilets']}','{$line['OfficeId']}','{$line['OwnershipType']}','{$line['ParkingDesc']}','{$line['PoolOptions']}','{$line['Pool']}','{$line['ReasonForSelling']}','{$line['SpecialFeatures']}','{$line['RoofOptions']}','{$line['RoomOptions']}','{$line['WallFinishes']}','{$line['Windows']}','{$line['StyleOptions']}','{$line['SecurityOptions']}','{$line['TempControl']}','{$line['StreetName']}','{$line['StreetNumber']}','{$line['Suburb']}','{$line['PropertyCategory']}','{$line['TypeOfProperty']}','{$line['UnitName']}','{$line['AgentContactName']}','{$line['Province']}','{$line['City']}','{$line['PostalCode']}','{$line['SellerEmail']}','{$line['Status']}','{$line['FeedType']}','{$line['MunRatesTaxes']}','{$line['MonthlyLevy']}')"); 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients
                (clnt_title,clnt_name,clnt_surname,clnt_street_name,clnt_street_no,clnt_complex_name,clnt_unit_no,clnt_suburb,clnt_city,clnt_cell,clnt_email,agnt_id,)
        values ({$line['SellerTitle']}','{$line['SellerFirstName']}','{$line['SellerSurname']}','{$line['StreetName']}','{$line['StreetNumber']}','{$line['UnitName']}','{$line['UnitNumber']}','{$line['Suburb']}','{$line['City']}','{$line['SellerMobileNumber']}','{$line['SellerEmail']}','{$line['AgentID']}')"); 
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM residential WHERE ListNumber={$line['ListNumber']}"); 
        echo "{$line['ListNumber']} was deleted <br/>"; 
    } 
 } 
 mysql_close($connect); 

?>
```

Now not all of these columns are compatible with their counter part column where it is supposed to be inserted into.

My question to you is, how do I save these incompatible strings into a variable and then insert them into the Database Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). PHP will convert the type automatically for you, and you're protected against Injection Attacks.

Actually, you should be using Prepared Statements everywhere in your code... building SQL from strings is a bad habit.